# Azure Cloud Service with a few IPs

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a single Cloud Service with two Web Roles (Web Site and Wcf Services).
Currently I use port 80 for the Web Site and 8080 for the Wcf Services.

Can I use different IPs for Web Site and Wcf Services (to utilize port 80 on both of them)?

I can create two Cloud Services, but that looks weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're both using the same Cloud Service, I don't think you can assign multiple IP addresses since the Cloud Service is tied to a specific URL (http://yourservice.cloudapp.net). The best option is probably to create two Cloud Services: yoursite.cloudapp.net and yourwcfservice.cloudapp.net.

Comment: Yes, this is how I changed it. Thanks